# Laravel5 whereRaw not working to parameterize column name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to build the column sent_storename with my whereRaw statement. But when I try to concatenate the values, the query doesn't work. When I fix the column it works. How can I do this?

```
$query = $this->model->getQuery()->where('products.environment_hash', $hash )->whereRaw('products.deleted_at is null');
$query->select('sku_config','name', 'stock_quantity', 'color', 'size', 'special_price', DB::raw('(special_price/default_price-1)*100 as profit_mark'));
$query->leftJoin('ads', 'ads.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
$query->whereRaw("products.sent_? = 0", array('storename'));
```

Comment: $query->whereRaw(str_replace('?', 'storename', 'products.sent_?') . " = 0");

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you'd be required to do this, if there is an underlying problem and you came up with this as a work around, maybe we can help you with the actual problem if you describe what it is.

Comment: @user3158900 I have several store_names (e.g. a, b, c, d). And each one has a field called (sent_a, sent_b, sent_c, etc). I just want to build the column name with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what is happening when you use `?` here.  It's not simple concatenation, it's parameter binding.  See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php.

However, concatenation (`.`) would work for you though.

```
$query->where("products.sent_".$storeName.", 0);
```

However this doesn't seem like good design because it requires you to do things like this as well as alter the table each time a new store is added.

If it's not too late, I would re-think this approach.  You could probably create a new table of `stores` each with their own `id`.  Then create a pivot table which contains the `product_id`, `store_id`, and the `sent` column.  Then you'd be able to take advantage of the `belongsToMany` relationships.